# Change theme in new TextMate?

Tags: textmate

I am new to TextMate.

Double click the .tmTheme file dont install and set the theme for me.

And There is no "Font&Color" tab in recent built TextMate, How can i change the theme?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

in TM2 you change your theme by selecting Theme from the the View menu.